# Error when connecting to SQL Server from client computer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I have a login form which does work. But every time I log in I get this error

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication

This only happens on client's PC.

Here is my current connection string:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=x,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=Test; User ID=joe; Password=momma; Integrated Security=False")
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
```

Comment: Is the database server configured to allow SQL authentication? The error suggests it's attempting Windows auth.

Comment: @DanGuzman If the server only allows windows auth then how can he be successful with user/pass on his machine? I am not challenging you, just wondering

Comment: @DanGuzman SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode is checked.

Comment: @howdy what if you supply `Integrated Security=False`

Comment: @djv Just tried it, I got the same error.

Comment: @djv, my comment on SQL auth was just to point out it's a prerequisite for SQL authentication. I suspect the connection string in the question is not the actual one used. Windows auth will not work on a PC that's not part of the domain (Client PC?) but could work on PCs that are part of the domain if the user has permissions to connect.

Comment: @DanGuzman The connection string being used is the one in the question. I was able to fix it by removing this code `If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open() End If` and chaging it to just `con.Open()`. No idea why that worked.

Comment: show us the sql server configuration.. it is a named instance or not?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/) and [Network Protocol for SQL Server Connection](https://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/)

Comment: Is the client's computer in the same Active Directory domain as the server? Otherwise Windows Auth won't work. Furthermore, Windows Auth does not use username and password, so if you were trying SQL Auth that then you definitely need `Integrated Security=False`